# android libgdx font isn't drawing

Tags: android, fonts, libgdx

I have got a background picture and want to draw text on it, but it isn't working.
There is only the picture on the screen.

```
private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
private Texture splsh;
private BitmapFont font;   

public void render(float arg0) 
{
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.draw(splsh, 0, 0);
    font.draw(spriteBatch, "test", 10, 480);
    spriteBatch.end();
}

public void show()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    splsh = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bg2.png"));
    font = new BitmapFont();                                                                        
    font.setColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: Try to edit the cordinates to something like 100, 100, maybe you drawing the text outside the sceen

Answer (score 0):

you should scale your font

```
font.setScale(0.2f);
```

change size according to your need...
and one more thing try drawing your font in center of screen, that way you can check that whether it is drawing or not